# Pycharm can't interprete behave

Tags: python, pycharm, python-behave

Helllo,

Im trying to do do tutorial from https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

and when im creating tutorial.feature in pycharm (by gherkin file), all the code is underlined and marked as wrong...

Here you can see my setup (i have pycharm pro) and in BDD i have behave.

[tutorial.feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzTBQ.png)
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhXRj.png)

Comment: but still, pycharm should recogonize it as a correct one? When you creating a gherking file you have a template for it but still underlined.

Answer (score 1):

Problem sovled.

I just deleted PyCharm Community + current Pro version and installed fresh Pro without importing settings (before i imported settings from community version).